# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table in SQLite3 database

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error when trying to migrate my data, which I am trying to troubleshoot but I cannot identify where the error is occurring. For context, I created a new app within my project for a webpage on change impacts, and I copied most of the code from my book app to start it out. It looks like somewhere, my code is mixing the two apps (must've been somewhere that I forgot to update) and is trying to add data into a table that doesn't exist (and shouldn't).

Any idea how to identify where this is happening, or any flags to look out that would be causing this?

change_impacts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class ChangeImpacts(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    current = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    future = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    stakeholder_group = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    people = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    process = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    technology = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.current

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('change_impacts:changeimpacts_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

book_crv/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Book(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    stakeholder_group = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    stakeholder_quadrant = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    representative = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    influence = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    impact = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    interest = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    perception = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('books_cbv:book_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, books_cbv, books_fbv, books_fbv_user, change_impacts, communications, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying books_cbv.0006_auto_20210107_2150...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: books_cbv_changeimpacts

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 232, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 261, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.delete_model(model)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 308, in delete_model
    super().delete_model(model)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 325, in delete_model
    self.execute(self.sql_delete_table % {
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: books_cbv_changeimpacts
```

migration:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.17 on 2021-01-08 03:50

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('books_cbv', '0005_changeimpacts'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='ChangeImpacts',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='book',
            name='description',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000),
        ),
    ]
```

makemigrations

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\Transformation Visualizer\django_crud-master\apps>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'books_cbv':
  books_cbv\migrations\0006_auto_20210108_0845.py
    - Delete model ChangeImpacts
    - Alter field description on book
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'theme',
    'communications',
    'change_impacts',
    'books_cbv',
    'books_fbv',
    'books_fbv_user',
    'widget_tweaks',    
]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `models.py` where this table is being referenced? Also, did you run `makemigrations` before running `migrate`?

Comment: Both models added, and yes I add makemigrations beforehand everytime

Comment: Can you add the contents of `0006_auto_20210107_2150.py` to the question? Did you move models from one app to the other?

Comment: Doesn't look like any issues with models. What about the actual migration file `0006_auto_20210107_2150` from your `books_cbv` app?

Comment: Added. Not sure why theres a delete model in there, because i did not delete anything

Answer (score 0):

the migrations show that the model has been deleted.
(see here)

```py
operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='ChangeImpacts',
        ),
```

If you are sure that the model is still in your table though, then you can delete that particular migration file and run the following to help django know it is actually there.

```py
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: When I remove this and recreate makemigrations, it still is trying to delete ChangeImpacts (see results added to OP). It also looks like the migration is being attempted within books_cbv instead of the entire project even though I initiate makemigrations at the folder above this.... Any thoughts why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure `ChangeImpact` model is still in `change_impacts/models.py`? The only reason for `makemigrations` to attempt to delete it, is because it can't find it any more.

Comment: Is `change_impact` app in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Confirm that change_impacts is in INSTALLED APPS (see above). And confirmed that the models file still contains ChangeImpacts and is in the right location